# ImageView as Mask or Parameter for images from web - How to?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I built an app and used an imageview (SmartImageView to be exactly, but i doubt that the problem) as reference for the place where I want my images to be, the thing is: the imageview has 50x50 px (set to wrap_content) but when I pull the images from web (favicons, to be exactly) if they are bigger than 60x60 instead of keeping the imageview size, they keep their own size.

I want my imageview to work as a mask and crop and/or resize the favicons to it's 50x50 size, how can I do it?

Heres the xml of the imageview:

```
    <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/favicon_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/favicon_example2" />
```

And here's the java bit of code that pulls the images to it:

```
linkImageView.setImageUrl(link.favicon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your height and width to `wrap_content` which means that it is going to resize itself to fit the content that you give it. If you want it to always be 50px no matter what size image you give it then you need to declare the size statically instead of `wrap_content`. And set your scaleType so the system knows how to manipulate the image should it be a different size. [See here for possible values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)

```
 <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
        android:id="@+id/favicon_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/favicon_example2" />
```

note that the use of the `px` unit is generally discouraged. `dp` is used more often because it can scale up or down for smaller and larger resolution devices. But if you want it to be the exact same pixels on every device then you must declare it with `px`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). You may want to have a calculated size or fixed size in dp when using ImageView.ScaleType properties.